# Nuke them until they glow -- am I right it's impossible?

Tags: radiation

Of course you'll kill them first, ignore that.

I'm not talking about any waste that may get deposited, that can be washed off.

The only mechanism I can see to glow is radioactive decay of isotopes created by neutron activation.  (Note that there is a question on Quora that simply dismisses this based on a lack of water--but the skin has a similar refractive index.)

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0969804316302184

says we need a beta particle of 263keV to go locally FTL.

Going down the elements by abundance in the human body:

Oxygen:  O19 - I can't find the decay energy but the 26 second half life means they're not glowing for long.

Carbon: C14 - 156keV decay energy, the beta particle doesn't go FTL.

Hydrogen:  H3 - 18keV decay energy, the beta particle doesn't go FTL.

Nitrogen:  N16 - I can't find the decay energy but it has a half life of 7 seconds--they're not going to glow for long

Calcium: C47 is energetic enough at 1.3MeV and has a half life of the better part of a week, but it's pretty much down there in the bones far from the skin surface.

Phosphorus: P32 is likewise energetic enough at 1.7MeV and a half life of a couple of weeks, but it's pretty much down there in the bones.

Could that actually create a glow?  (Perceivable to the unaided eye in complete darkness.)  Or is there anything else I'm missing that could create a glow?  (Or would it only show up where the calcium & phosphorus are exposed--the teeth, probably showing up where the beta particles hit the tissue of the mouth?)

Comment: put em underwater and Cherenkov radiation can produce a glow.

Comment: @John But what isotope??

Comment: anything that emits beta particles or positrons.

Comment: Radium glows a little but you can add phosphorus to make it brighter no need to resort to WMD.

Comment: @John Not everything--note that I specifically rejected tritium and C-14 as not being energetic enough for Cherenkov radiation.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious answer, nuke them until they **melt.** The glow will last until they cools down, but then any solution would have a strictly limited duration. Consider [trinitite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinitite).

Comment: I don't really think there would be a "them" at that point to glow.  Besides, you can't melt flesh, can you?  Wouldn't it oxidize instead?